# Help with logic

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a number of objects. They can be sorted into groups. When a user "drags" an object into a group, I INSERT a record into my db

```
INSERT INTO t1
  (group_id, item_id, project_id, user_id) 
VALUES 
  ($groupID, $itemID, $projectID, $userID)
```

There can be multiple objects in the same group and those objects can be moved from one group to another. When I move the objects into another group, I don't need to create another record, but rather only update group_id.

---

EDIT:

I think I need to do something like this afterall:

```
table structure
t1.id
t1.group_id
t1.item_id
t1.project_id
t1.user_id

if ("SELECT id, group_id FROM t1 
   WHERE item_id = $itemID
   AND project_id = $projectID
   AND user_id = $userID")) {

   // if found 
   UPDATE t1 
   SET group_id = $groupID
   WHERE id = $ID

} else {

   INSERT INTO t1
   (group_id, item_id, project_id, user_id) 
   VALUES ($groupID, $itemID, $projectID, $userID)
```

Comment: You should have a seperate table for groups

Comment: And what is the question? Do you ask for the solution to make it automatically, after every time you change $groupID for some object? It is possible. Ask the question - you need SQL query, some advice in some specific topic, database structure, ORM proposal or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like u should place a if statement when moving from a group to another group to update only the object being move. Say for instance if I am selecting an object from its initial(beginning) space I would add the insert statement. If I am moving an object that has already been grouped to another group I would add an update statement. Finally if I am taking an item out of all groups completely I would issue  a delete statement that will remove the object from the table.

```
pseudo code

if object = new
{
INSERT INTO t1 (group_id, item_id, project_id, user_id) 
VALUES ($groupID, $itemID, $projectID, $userID)
}
if object = group
}
UPDATE t1 
SET group_id = $newgroupID
WHERE item_id = $itemID;
}
if object = banned
}
delete from t1 where item_id = $itemID
}
```

This sequence of code should be placed on each container that you are dragging your objects to so that it can check for the proper requirements.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards but was not sure if this was too much code solution. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one query using insert ... on duplicate key update.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for details.

Assuming that item_id is a key, you can do

```
INSERT INTO t1
  (group_id, item_id, project_id, user_id) 
VALUES 
  ($groupID, $itemID, $projectID, $userID)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE group_id = $groupID
```

Comment: This is a great idea. I can use it in my case because I can have multiple items in a group, but I will remember to use it next time where I deal with unique values. Thanks for the suggestion. +1

Comment: @santa you can update multiple items - take a look at the documentation for the insert command, you'll see that you can do multiple updates separated by commas: ...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE group_id = $groupID, otheritem = $someval

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add a surrogate primary key so you can you can identify uniquely every row. Then you can make an update like this:

```
UPDATE t1 SET group_id = $newgroupid WHERE id = $objectid;
```